# Why doesn't Excel recognize the variable names in my SUMPRODUCT function?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm new to VBA. I keep getting a #NAME error when I try to run the code below. It seems Excel does not recognize the 2 arguments in the SUMPRODUCT() function, as they are user-defined variables whose values come from 2 different worksheets. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
Public Sub myMacro()

Dim firstArray As Range

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate ' Activate the worksheet named "Sheet1"

    Set firstArray = Range("A2:C40")

Dim secondArray As Range

    Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate ' Activate the worksheet named "Sheet2"

    Set secondArray = Range("A2:D40") ' Select the desired range, assign it to secondArray

Dim emptyCells As Range

    Worksheets("Sheet3").Activate ' Activate the worksheet named "Sheet3"

    Set emptyCells = Range("A1:Z1")

    emptyCells.Formula = "=SUMPRODUCT(firstArray, secondArray)"  ' ---- PROPER SYNTAX, BUT GIVES ME A #NAME ERROR

End Sub
```

Comment: you have them inside of your quotes, so they aren't actually variables in that case... they are just part of the literal string.

Comment: The worksheet formula "=SUMPRODUCT(firstArray, secondArray)" is expecting two named ranges "firstArray" and "secondArray".  Your VBA varaible names are not present in the context of the worksheet formula when Excel is trying to evaluate it.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use a construct like below.

`emptyCells.Formula = "=SUMPRODUCT(" & "'" & firstArray.Parent.Name & "'!" & firstArray.Address & "," & "'" & secondArray.Parent.Name & "'!" & secondArray.Address & ")"`